# How to get reverted error name with ethers in javascript?

Tags: solidity, ganache, hardhat

I write a solidty code and also a custom error like this:

```
error TestObject__IndexNotFound();

function getProductChain(uint256 index) public view returns(SupplyChain memory){
    if (index > (counter - 1) || index < 0){
        revert TestObject__IndexNotFound();
    }
    SupplyChain memory spChain = supplyChain[index];
    return spChain;
}
```

But when i catch this error, the name of this error doesn't show:

```
 try{
     const transactionResponse = await contract.getProductChain(index);
     console.log(transactionResponse);
 }catch(error){
     console.log(error);
 }
```

Instead, it just writes 'revert' with no reason!. I can write require with string but I want to use error and revert. Last time when I used ethers and hardhat (node), the reverted error
was shown in my console. But now it doesn't. I used ethers and ganache this time:

```
Error: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason 
string....
```

Answer (score 1):

In ethers v6, you can use `error.data` that can be decoded from the contract to get the reverted error.

```js
} catch (e) {
    if (e.data && contract) {
      const decodedError = contract.interface.parseError(e.data);
      console.log(`Transaction failed: ${decodedError?.name}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Error in widthrawContract:`, e);
    }
  }
```

---

**Detailled Example**

Solidity

```
  modifier onlyOwner() {
        if (msg.sender != i_owner) revert FundMe__NotOwner();
        _;
    }
```

Browser code

```
export const widthrawContract = async () => {
  if (!isCryptoWalletAvailable()) return;
  let provider, signer, contract;
  try {
    console.log(`Widthrawing wallet...`);
    provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
    signer = await provider.getSigner();
    contract = new ethers.Contract(FUND_ME_CONTRACT_ADDR, FUND_ME_ABI, signer);

    await contract.withdraw({});
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.data && contract) {
      const decodedError = contract.interface.parseError(e.data);
      console.log(`Transaction failed: ${decodedError?.name}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Error in widthrawContract:`, e);
    }
  }
};
```

Error received from the browser:

> Transaction failed: FundMe__NotOwner

[In ethers V5, it's tiny different](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/3027#discussioncomment-2920447)

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a similar question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/159326/124816) but I will do answer your question based on your example code too.

Here's how you can detect your error with ethers.js quite easily using [ethers-decode-error](https://github.com/superical/ethers-decode-error).

Install `ethers-decode-error` in your project:

```
npm install ethers-decode-error --save
```

Next, the following code will help you get the name of the custom error in your solidity contract:

```typescript
import { ErrorDecoder, DecodedError } from 'ethers-decode-error'

// You only have to do this once in your entire application
const errorDecoder = ErrorDecoder.create([contract.interface])

 try{
   const transactionResponse = await contract.getProductChain(index);
   console.log(transactionResponse);
 }catch(err){
  const { name } = await errorDecoder.decode(err)

  // Prints "TestObject__IndexNotFound" which is what you have named the error in your contract
  console.log('Custom error name:', name)
 }
```

If you want to match the different possible custom errors reverting from your contract with your own custom error messages, here's one way of doing it:

```typescript
 try{
   const transactionResponse = await contract.getProductChain(index);
   console.log(transactionResponse);
 }catch(err){
  const decodedError = await errorDecoder.decode(err)
  const reason = customReasonMapper(decodedError)

  // Prints "This is a custom message for TestObject__IndexNotFound from my contract."
  console.log('Custom error message:', reason)
 }

const customReasonMapper = ({ name, reason }: DecodedError): string => {
  switch (name) {
    case 'TestObject__IndexNotFound':
      return `This is a custom message for ${name} from my contract.`

    // You can match other custom errors you may have in your contract here...
    // case 'MyOtherError': ...

    // Captures other error messages
    default:
      return reason ?? 'There was an error'
  }
}
```

You can find more examples for handling solidity custom errors [here](https://github.com/superical/ethers-decode-error?tab=readme-ov-file#custom-errors) such as getting parameter values of custom errors, etc. :)